# Maximum sum in a Subarray

Tags: c, max, sub-array

> You're given an array of N integer numbers.
>   The maximal sum of the array is the maximal sum of the elements of a nonempty consecutive subarray of this array.
>   For example, the maximal sum of the array [1, -2, 3, -2, 5] is 6 because the sum of the subarray [3, -2, 5] is 6 and it is impossible to achieve greater subarray sum.
>   Now you're allowed to remove no more than one element from the given array. What is the maximal possible maximal sum of the resulting array you can achieve by doing so?

I am testing my code with my own test cases. I am getting correct output on dev-c++.
But when I test my code online I get wrong answer. I am not able to find out what is the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct result{
    long long int start;
    long long int end;
    long long int sum;
}res;
long long int find_max(long long int a[],long long int n)
{
    long long int max=LLONG_MIN;
    long long int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        if(a[i]>max)
            max=a[i];
    }
    return max;
}
long long int max_sub(long long int a[],long long int n)
{
    long long int i;
    long long int min,sum1=0;
    struct result max,max_curr,*maxsub;
    maxsub=calloc(sizeof(res),n);
    max.sum=LLONG_MIN;
    max_curr=max;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        if(max_curr.sum<0)
        {
            max_curr.sum=a[i];
            max_curr.start=i;
            max_curr.end=i;
        }
        else
        {
            max_curr.sum+=a[i];
            max_curr.end=i;
        }
        if(max_curr.sum>max.sum)
        {
            max=max_curr;
        }
        maxsub[i]=max;
    }
    min=0;
    for(i=maxsub[n-1].start;i<=maxsub[n-1].end;++i)
    {
        if(a[i]<0)
        {
            if(min==0 || a[i]<min)
                min=a[i];
        }
    }
    sum1=maxsub[n-1].sum-min;
    return sum1;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        long long int n,i;
        scanf("%lld",&n);
        long long int a[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;++i)
            scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
        long long int sum=0;
        sum=find_max(a,n);
        if(sum<=0)
        {
            printf("%lld\n",sum);
        }
        else
        {
            sum=max_sub(a,n);
            printf("%lld\n",sum);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 'remove one element' by making it empty, or you also shrink the array's size by removing that element?

Comment: shrink the array's size by removing that element

Comment: Here is an array with size 6: [1, 2, 3, -1, 5, 1]. When I run your program, I get the result 12. But it seems to me the result should be 11?

Comment: I am allowed to remove atmost one element from the array.If i remove -1 the maximal sum becomes 12 and the array becomes [1,2,3,5,1] which is the resulting subarray.

Comment: Test your code for the following array `[ 1, -4, 3, -1, 1]`. It will give wrong result `3`, but actual result should be `4` which will be obtained by removing `-4` from `[1, -4, 3]`.

Comment: This is a question from ongoing CodeChef SnackDown 2016 Qualifier, kindly refrain from posting the solution or help, as it is a clear violation of CodeChef [Code Of Conduct](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/18662/does-codechef-have-any-code-of-conduct).

Answer (score 4):

Please close this thread. OP is trying to cheat in an online competition going on right now, by posting the questions here.

Answer (score 4):

Well , This is not fair , people have been working hard to crack it . This is part of ongoing online competition on code-chef , Please close this thread .

EDIT : The contest is over now , Please be open to discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this array {1, -100, 6, -50, 5}.
You are removing minimum element in **subarray** with maximum sum but according to your problem you can remove atmost one element from **original array** so as to maximize the sum of its contiguous array and thats why you are getting a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you have implemented the Kadane's algorithm to find the max sum subarray in an array.
Given array is:  [1, -2, 3, -2, 5] 
Kadane's Result : [3, -2 ,5 ]

Now what you're doing is: removing the minimum element in the subarray, which is unfortunately incorrect. 
Now suppose , Given array is: [1, -2, 3, -2, 5, -33, 5] 
Kadane's Result : [3, -2 ,5 ] 
Your Output: [3, 5] , i.e 8

But here the correct answer would be selecting subarray [3, -2, 5, -33, 5]
and eliminating '-33'
and which results the output to be: 11. (3+5+5-2)

Thanks. 
PS: My first answer on stackoverflow. This is only one exception I discussed about, there are many more.
Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

Why you subtract least number from result:

```
/*min=0;
for(i=maxsub[n-1].start;i<=maxsub[n-1].end;++i)
{
    if(a[i]<0)
    {
        if(min==0 || a[i]<min)
            min=a[i];
    }
}*/
sum1=maxsub[n-1].sum;//-min;
return sum1; // Works fine
```

Comment: As shown in the statement, the maximal sum of the initial array is 6, but if you remove the fourth element (i.e. -2), then the array [1, -2, 3, 5] will have subarray [3, 5] and the value of the maximal sum will be equal to 8.    Explanation given in the problem

Comment: Due to this i subtract largest negative number in the array

Comment: Where you test online? Can you provide input numbers in test

Comment: Maybe online checker uses only positive numbers to check your program. In that case, it does remove no one element.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
long long int sum;
long long int rightsum(long long int a[], long  int n, long int start, long int end) {

    long int i;
    long long int max_so_far=INT_MIN,max_ending_here=0;
    for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
    {
       max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i];
        if (max_so_far < max_ending_here)
        {
            max_so_far = max_ending_here;
        }  
    }
    return max_so_far;
}
long long int leftsum(long long int a[], long long int n, long long int start, long long int end) {

    long int i;
    long long int max_so_far=INT_MIN,max_ending_here=0;
    for(i=end;i>=start;i--)
    {
      max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i];
        if (max_so_far < max_ending_here)
        {
            max_so_far = max_ending_here;
        }  
    }
    return max_so_far;
}
long long int maxSum(long long int a[],long int n) {

    long long int sum = rightsum(a, n, 1, n - 1);
    long int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i ++) {

        long long int l = leftsum(a, n, 0, i - 1);
        long long int r = rightsum(a, n, i + 1, n - 1);


        if (((i > 0) && (i < n - 1)) && ( l>=0) && (r>0) && (l+r>sum)) {

            sum = l+r;
            if(sum<sum+a[i])
            {
                sum=sum+a[i];
            }

        }


        else if ((i > 0) && (l >= r) && (l>sum)) {
            sum = l;

            if(sum<sum+a[i])
            {
                sum=sum+a[i];
            }

        }

        else if ((i < n - 1) ) {
            sum = r;

            if(sum<sum+a[i])
            {
                sum=sum+a[i];
            }

        }
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    long long i,n;
    long long int a[100000];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t!=0)
    {
        scanf("%ld",&n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
        }
        printf("%lld\n",maxSum(a,n));
        t--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but its not  an  efficient way. How  to make it more efficient